# How to add second Apple ID to my account to shop in App Store in a different country

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, apple-id

I live and work in the UK and in Germany. My first Apple ID is registered and linked to App Sore UK. I can't shop in the German App Store with that, but the App I need is not available in the UK store. I have set up a second Apple ID with a German email address, but how can I add this to my iPad so that I can shop in the German App Store?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings-> iTunes & App Store then tap your UK Apple ID and tap "Log Out". Then just sign in with your German Apple ID. After you've downloaded the app, you should be able to switch back to the UK Apple ID in the same way without anything being affected.

Comment: You are a star RedEagle2000, after getting frustrated for nearly 2 hours trying to watch an Amazon Prime film in Germany for which the German App is needed and having been close to delete my main UK Apple ID ( which probably had cost me all my itune library) all that was needed was a switch off/on. Thank you for your help - 100 cudos for you!

Comment: Glad I could help, please click the green checkmark to accept this answer so others can learn from it as well.